# VSCode: "Format uri ('http://localhost:%s') must contain exactly two substitution placeholders" error with docker

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Trying to set up VSCode to debug a nodejs app in a Docker container.

It builds and run the containers but then I eventually get this error dialog
[image: error dialog]

```
Format uri ('http://localhost:%s') must contain exactly two substitution placeholders
```

and I cannot do any debugging.

I can't find this error anywhere in any of the VSCode output/terminal windows.  And I don't have that format string *anywhere* in my code or config files.

For what it's worth, the application runs fine in the Docker container (e.g. responds to HTTP requests, etc)

And here's my run command that VSCode shows in the terminal window:

```
docker run -dt --name "xxnodejsservicetemplate-dev" -e "DEBUG=*" -e "NODE_ENV=development" --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio-code" -p "3000:3000" -p "9229:9229" "xxnodejsservicetemplate:latest" yarn dev --debug 0.0.0.0:9229
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Docker wants to replace the scheme and the port.  At this time, VS Code is only adding a substitution for the port.  So, instead of this format:

```
    "dockerServerReadyAction": {
        "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s"
    }
```

Use this:

```
    "dockerServerReadyAction": {
        "uriFormat": "%s://localhost:%s"
    }
```